# Appropriate button copy if the user wants sales to contact them

Tags: user-expectation, copywriting, contact-us, empty-state

We're integrating our app with another app via an iFrame.

In the "parent" app, the user would already be logged-in before they can download our app. So ie, we would already have their information.

Once they choose to download our app, their organization will still need to be onboarded before they can use it.

So the user clicks on the "Contact us" button, this will immediately send their information to our Sales team, and takes them to a "We'll reach out to your shortly..." page.

What would be the appropriate copy here? "Contact us" just feels unconventional because that typically leads to a contact form or email, but as mentioned, we would already have the user's info via the "parent" app, so we don't want them to have to type those again.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Once they choose to download our app, their organization will still need to be onboarded before they can use it.*

It seems that <kbd>Activate</kbd> could be an option, with three states showing the performing action:

- Activate
- Processing
- Activated

[image]

Comment: That's great! My only hesitation is that "Activate" might imply that it will immediately get activated upon clicking the button? They can't get activated right away since the Sales team will have the be alerted first.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a question about the copy. My question would be, why not just tell them what you're trying to do/the system is doing in the background?

Make a subheader saying something like

"We already have your information because you're logged in. Click the button below to request for onboarding."

<kbd>Request for Onboarding</kbd>

We'll send an e-mail to you@site

After the user clicks that button, you should reply with a prompt saying that the request has been received and the user will be notified in a few days or whatever time it takes for you to reply back.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really "contact us" is it, especially when the user is already in contact with you by using this form.
It's more of an "allow *us* to contact you".
And it hardly needs a separate "We'll reach out to your shortly..." page.

But what's really missing in this question is *why* they need to press that button at all.

Couldn't it simply say something like:

> Your **organization** is not in our system yet.
> Our sales team will soon e-mail you (you@site) to request the appropriate details.

But really, why does the sales team need to be involved at all?
Can't the form simply ask for the appropriate information *now*?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have their information, it's best to set the expectations before hand.

My Two Cents

**Option 1:**
I think something in the lines of "I am in, get in touch" along with some helper text to set the next step. This will

**Option 2: "Schedule a Consultation"**

Supporting Copy:
"Ready to elevate your experience with [Your App Name]? Click below to schedule a personalized consultation. Our team will reach out shortly to understand your needs and guide you through a tailored onboarding journey. Let's make your [Your App Name] experience exceptional!

****Option 3: "Start Onboarding, I am in!""**
Ready to elevate your experience with [Your App Name]? Click below to schedule a personalized consultation. Our team will reach out shortly to understand your needs and guide you through a tailored onboarding journey. Let's make your [Your App Name] experience exceptional!